# Android Studio when import new module the project don't show at project structure

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mobile

Android Studio when import new module the project don't show at the project structure

I have two android projects and I need to add two projects together to open activity from app one to another app
when adding the project as a module I cant link between two project

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XLML7.png)

and when add manually using

implementation project(':test')

I show this error
 [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHd32.png)

Comment: You have compile errors. When you have compiles errors the project is not always fully built, so you won't be able to see all references. Also post your `settings.gradle` here

Answer (score 0):

Would you care to check if your settings.gradle have:

```
include ':app'
include ':test'
```

Also, check if on your test build.gradle you are using 
`apply plugin: 'com.android.library'` instead of
`apply plugin: 'com.android.application'`

Now what I'm not sure if you are working on two different apps and want to open app B from app A? if that's the case you can try different approaches which I recommend reading about App Link so you can achieve this.

https://developer.android.com/training/app-links

Comment: I try this but the same problem